# _sre.SRE_Pattern object is not callable if concatenate with another

Tags: python, regex, csv, typeerror

I'm newbie with python and I have a problem with regex and csv writing.

here is the code

```
import re
import csv

match_text = re.compile(r'[^(<a href="/employer/\d+?\>)].+[^(\s</a>)]', re.UNICODE)
match_hh_company_url = re.compile(r'/employer/\d+', re.UNICODE)

def listing_employers():
    ...
    ## making a list with some data
    ...
    source_list = match_page.findall(data)
    source_list = set(source_list)
    return source_list

def w_to_file(f_name, source_list):
    with open(f_name, 'wb') as csvfile:
        bankwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel')
        for each in source_list:
            bankwriter.writerow(match_text.findall(each) + match_hh_company_url(each))

w_to_file('bank_base', listing_employers())
```

All is fine, but there are problem with concatenating `match_text.findall(each) + match_hh_company_url(each)` - it throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "salebase.py", line 41, in <module>
    w_to_file('bank_base', listing_employers())
  File "salebase.py", line 33, in w_to_file
    bankwriter.writerow(match_text.findall(each) + match_hh_company_url(each))
TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Pattern' object is not callable
```

It is ok, if I use only one `match_`, but does not work with `+`, and thats strange.
I've tried to model situation in shell, and it works!!:

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.compile('\d{3}')
>>> n = re. compile('[a-z]')
>>> a = ['111 a', 'a333', 'f444b']
>>> for x in a:
...     print m.findall(x)
... 
['111']
['333']
['444']
>>> for x in a:
...     print m.findall(x) + n.findall(x)
... 
['111', 'a']
['333', 'a']
['444', 'f', 'b']
>>>
```

If it's matters, I'm making `source_list` from matching expressions with blocks of text and place it in list. This is the meaning of listed_employers() function. Full code here: http://pastebin.com/bimhfAtn

So can anyone help me, whats the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call `findall` on that object:

```
match_hh_company_url.findall(each)
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r'')
>>> r()
Traceback (most recent call last):
    r()
TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Pattern' object is not callable

>>> r.findall('')
['']
```

Comment: I'm little, blind, mad man %) I've looking what I've missed for 1,5 hour! Thank you very much! :)